# Can you use MITM to hijack a public key meant for key based signing?

Tags: public-key, signature, key-exchange

After reading ["Verify the identity of sender"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454048/what-is-the-difference-between-encrypting-and-signing-in-asymmetric-encryption/#48234268) , which was part of an answer on StackOverflow, I was wondering if the following is possible:

Based on part II, if I am sitting between Alice and Bob:

- Can I not wait for Alice to send her public key to Bob.
- I block this key and discard it, and send my own public key instead.
- Bob then thinks this public key is from Alice.
- I send any message I want now, signed with my own private key.
- Bob 'verifies' these messages with my public key, and thinks all of these messages are from Alice.

Is this scenario possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is a standard MITM attack.  This is why we typically use some sort of out-of-band method for verifying public keys.  For example, in OpenPGP, we can use key signatures from trusted parties or in-person verification, and in TLS, we use certificate authorities.  For SSH host keys, we can verify a fingerprint on a trusted website or using DNSSEC.  There are even more ways of doing the same thing: you can download someone's SSH keys from GitHub and there are sites like Keybase which tie multiple accounts to a set of credentials cryptographically, in addition to other various techniques.

Ultimately, in order to trust the integrity of the messages, you have to verify the public key somehow independently.